# Comparing/diffing tuning files

Tags: c, bash, scripting, diff, xargs

I have two files which look something like this:

```
#define TUNING_CONST 55
#define OTHER_TUNING_CONST 107
...
```

and

```
#define TUNING_CONST 65
#define OTHER_TUNING_CONST 93
...
```

You can think of these as an automatically-generated file and its static base. I would like to compare them, but I can't find a good way. `diff` isn't apparently able to see that the lines are the same apart from the constants. I tried a hacky approach with `xargs` but it was a little tricky... here's a start, showing each of the constants in the other file matched up line by line. But it doesn't show the name or the original constant, so it's not useful at this point.

```
egrep -o '^#define \S+' tuning.h | egrep -o '\S+$' | xargs -I % egrep "%" basetune.h | egrep -o '[0-9]+$'
```

This is surely a common case -- lots of programs generate tuning data -- and it can't be that rare to want to see how things change programmatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you add a C tag? It's easy to write C code for this but I don't see any C code in the Q

Comment: To me the question is a bit unclear. You write: "diff isn't apparently able to see that the lines are the same apart from the constants" hmm... so how would you like the output to look?

Comment: Concatenate both files, sort, then the prefixes _should_ be adjacent... Maybe you `grep` or `sed` to select only the #defines first... Your question shows a sliver of input and no expected output example.

Comment: `git diff --color-words`

Comment: `wdiff`; `icdiff`; `ccdiff`; `xxdiff`; ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question lacks a clear description of desired/expected output. Consequently any attempt to answer will be pure guessing.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I didn't have a particular output format in mind; I wanted to see what was easiest to do with existing tools. It looks like Diego Torres Milano found a great solution that certainly doesn't use a format I would have thought of!

Comment: @SupportUkraine But regardless, slava Ukraini!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what the expected output should be like, but here there's an option

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.2,1.3,2.3 <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
```

output

```
OTHER_TUNING_CONST 107 93
TUNING_CONST 55 65
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Final command: `join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.2,1.3,2.3 <(cat src/kernel/gmp/tune.h | ./preprocess_slightly.py | sort) <(sort Olinux-x86_64/tune.h) | egrep -v '\s+(-?[0-9]+)\s\1'`

Comment: You can avoid `cat` and use just `./preprocess_slightly.py <file`

Comment: That file isn't designed to be called with a filename; it expects arguments to be of the form `-Dfoo`, `-Ufoo`, or `-Dfoo=value`. But yes, I agree on avoiding `cat` when possible.

Comment: That's different `<` redirection is done by the shell, the command does not see it